# How to access hidden field from usercontrol

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a hidden variable in my aspx page i.e mainpage.aspx

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hdnCommonvCode" />
```

mainpage.aspx contains tabcontainer control. On each tab an usercontrol is added. If i try to access this hidden field `alert($find("<%=hdnCommonvasCode.ClientID %>"));` from usercontrol it shows compiler error msg

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'hdnCommonvCode' does not exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried like this `var hidx = document.getElementById('hdnCommonvCode');`